# Bootstrap left sidebar toggle menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I got a script for Bootstrap sidebar toggle menu. It works fine for my needs.

Right now the menu is toggling using Toggle Menu button, that is fine.But I need to close the menu if I click, out side of it.

Please check **[this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5j3mypcs/)**

and help me out. Thanks.

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this you have to play with jquery functions like `.hasClass`, `.trigger`, `.is` etc. What i did is, i checked the classes on click and then according to them i wrote this code. Please check

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/5j3mypcs/5/)

In detail : First i check the class which is toggling on click of `a href` so i made a condition that if `#wrapper`has toggled class then we will trigger the click event on `#menu-toggle` but also we have to careful that click should be on body but not the a href of side bar menu that's why i have added another condition with !tag. Hope you will understand and if not then let me know.

Comment: My pleasure and happy that  you accepted as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a window event to check where you are clicking,

Here is a snnipet :

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});

$(window).click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if(e.target.id =="menu-toggle") return;
               
   if($(e.target).closest('#sidebar-wrapper').length==0){
        // small device toogled class added auto so remove it
        if($("#wrapper").width() < 768 )
           $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
        else
           $("#wrapper").addClass("toggled");
   }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
```

Comment: Check my answer , the click reverse ( open menu ) in small screen , so above snippet I managed to always do close menu whatever been in small or large screen